# Replace a checked exception with a runtime exception?

Tags: java, exception

Given that I basically want to eliminate checked exception usage and transform them to runtime exceptions, I would normally be doing something like this:

```
try {
    file.read();
} catch (IOException e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
}
```

There are several disadvantages to doing this, but the one that irritates me the most is that my runtime exception would contain a nested stacktrace. Basically I would like to re-throw the  "IOException" as a RuntimeException (or "IORuntimeException") with the original message and stacktrace, so I can avoid the useless nested stacktrace. The "fact" that I have re-thrown the exception somewhere in the middle seems like just useless noise to me.

Is this possible ? Is there any library that does this ?

Comment: Is [this](http://robaustin.wikidot.com/rethrow-exceptions) helpful?

Comment: If you're irritated by nested stacktraces, you're gonna hate most frameworks and libraries, which tend to use them extensively. I'd just get used to it if I were you.

Comment: @KazekageGaara, good one. I'd upvote that if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @artbristol I know, but I can do my part to minimize the problem and avoid 400 line stacktraces.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39719370/435605

Answer (score 4):

[Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/disableCheckedExceptions.html) allows you to disable checked exceptions altogether.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's too much of a hack to me. I'd rather just do it myself somewhere

Comment: I doubt if there is a non-hacky solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Follow up from my comment. Here's an [article](http://robaustin.wikidot.com/rethrow-exceptions) that has to throw some light on the issue. It uses `sun.misc.Unsafe` to rethrow exceptions without wrapping them.

Answer (score 2):

```
class IORuntimeException extends RuntimeException {

    final IOException ioex;

    public IORuntimeException(IOException ioex) {
        this.ioex = ioex;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return ioex.getMessage();
    }

    @Override
    public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
        return ioex.getStackTrace();
    }

    //@Override
    // ...
}
```

(Full class available [here](http://ideone.com/swUom), as produced by Eclipse "Generate Delegate Methods" macro.)

Usage:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    throw new IORuntimeException(ioex);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it cannot be generalized for any `Exception` type, and thus causes too much boilerplate and code duplication.

Comment: Yes, but the type information is lost. Only if Java had reified generics... then we could have done this with generics.

Comment: An interesting aspect of this response is that it does not really work ;) "fillInStackTrace" is called from the the throwable constructor, meaning the member variable in the subclass hasnt been initialized.

Comment: Ah, so remove @Override ... fillInStackTrace then?

Answer (score 2):

If you're considering the other answer's use of Unsafe (I recommend not, but anyway), another option is to abuse generics to throw a checked exception with this evil pair of methods (from http://james-iry.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/on-removing-java-checked-exceptions-by.html):

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private static <T extends Throwable, A> 
     A pervertException(Throwable x) throws T {
      throw (T) x;
   }


   public static <A> A chuck(Throwable t) {
      return Unchecked.
        <RuntimeException, A>pervertException(t);
   }
```

You might also check out `com.google.common.base.Throwables.getRootCause(Throwable)` and just print its (root) stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you actually NEED checked Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 8 there's another way:

```
try {
  // some code that can throw both checked and runtime exception
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw rethrow(e);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Throwable> RuntimeException rethrow(Throwable throwable) throws T {
    throw (T) throwable; // rely on vacuous cast
}
```

* More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39719455/435605).